# What are the closest or related categorical concepts to applicative functors?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor says

> In functional programming, an applicative functor is a structure
>   intermediate between functors and monads, in that they allow
>   sequencing of functorial computations (unlike plain functors) but
>   without deciding on which computation to perform on the basis of the
>   result of a previous computation (unlike monads). Applicative functors
>   are the programming equivalent of lax monoidal functors with tensorial
>   strength in category theory.

I would like to know more about the categorical concepts for applicative functors, but I couldn't find "lax monoidal functors with tensorial strength" in *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.  In the book, what are the closest  or related categorical concepts to applicative functors?

Thanks.

Comment: I've asked this to myself.  All I came up with was that applicatives functors preserve small products, which in category theory is known simply as ``preserving products''. That covers a lot of ground. Wikipedia says lax monoidal functors, but that assumes categories are monoidal and functional programming categories need not be, so I don't buy it, but perhaps someone will explain.

Comment: "Categories for the Working Mathematician" is not at all the be-all, end-all references for categorical concepts, and there's certainly been a lot of work since it was published as well. The nLab does a fairly good job of providing an encyclopedic reference for categorical concepts, e.g. [lax monoidal functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+functor) with [tensorial strengths](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensorial+strength).