# What are the concepts for a generalized arrow from an object to an arrow, and mapping on such generalized arrows?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science

In a category,

- what is the concept for "a generalized arrow from an object to an arrow"?  For example, in programming language, such a generalized arrow is a curried function, i.e. a function which has a single parameter and returns a function.
- what is the concept for a mapping that maps "a generaized arrow from an object to an arrow"  to "another generalized arrow from an object to an arrow" (I think  [an applicative functor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295710/what-are-the-closest-or-related-categorical-concepts-to-applicative-functors) is such a mapping, but with more "generalization" on arrows.) We know that an endofunctor  maps "an arrow"  to "another arrow".

Thanks.

Comment: Curryfication has nothing to do with arrows from object to arrows. It is an arrow from an object to another one, the second one just happens to be a "space of arrows" $A^B$. You're confusing $\mapsto$ and $\to$ I think